# Set Options when Loading Pinterest Asynchronously with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, modernizr, pinterest, yepnope

I'm loading Pinterest and other Social Media scripts via Modernizr.load() [which is essentially using yepnope.js]

```
Modernizr.load([
     // other libs ommited for brevity
    '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js'
]);
```

I want to be able to set an option to enable the hover event, similarly to what the attribute `data-pin-hover` as shown at https://developers.pinterest.com/on_hover_pin_it_buttons/ does.

Any ideas?  TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do to add this effect, they are (almost always) loaded in via iframes, and therefore not scriptable/styleable by you.

The only way to do this would be for the script to natively support this feature, like how pinterest does.